# Recovering public key from scalar multiplication inverse

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have two keypairs on the curve `curve25519`

```
k1 --> (a, aG)
k2 --> (b, bG)
```

I can compute and verify that `a(bG) = b(aG)`.

Lets say `k = a (bG)`, I'm computing scalar inverse of `a` which is `pow(a, -1)` and computing `pow(a, -1) a (bG)` and expecting that it will be equal to `(bG)` but i see its not equal to `bG`.

From `a(bG)` by only knowing `a` and `aG`, is it possible to know `bG`?

Comment: Hint: Choose how you define/compute `pow(a, -1)` according to the property you want for the quantity `pow(a, -1) a`. That's _not_  `pow(a, -1) a = 1` in the field $\mathbb F_{2^{255}-19}$, nor in the field $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was thinking like multiple of any scalar variable with its  inverse is congruent to 1 modp in any prime field.

Comment: Yes, $a\,a^{-1}\equiv 1$ in any prime field (and any ring when the inverse $a^{-1}$ is defined). But $a^{-1}$ is dependent on the field/ring, and you need to choose the one appropriate for your goal in the problem. Again what property do you want $a\,a^{-1}$ to have?

Comment: I'm doing the point mul to blind the point, so by doing ```a a <sup>-1</sup>``` I'm looking to nullify the effect of point multiplication of a on a given point in the curve25519.
For example in my case by doing `aG` is a point that hides `a`, and if B blinds the point `aG` by multiplying it with `b`, i.e `b(aG)`, then I rewrite that as `a(bG)` and then if i do scalar multiplication of that point with `a<sup>-1<sup>`, i,e `a<sup>-1<sup>a(bG)`, i was expecting that I might be having `(bG)` and since the `bG` is public I can verify that B done the blinding of the point `aG`.

Comment: You need a library to do a modular multiplicative inverse, where the modulus is the group size, which as fgrieu has pointed out is 2^252+27742317777372353535851937790883648493 for curve25519

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On curve25519, from $a(bG)$ by only knowing $a$ and $aG$, is it possible to know $bG$?

Yes. We can compute $bG$ as $(a^{-1}\bmod n)(a(bG))$, where $n$ is the order of $G$, with $n=2^{252}+27742317777372353535851937790883648493$.

Proof: By definition of the order of $G$, it holds $nG=\mathcal O$ where $\mathcal O$ is the neutral of point addition. By definition of $a^{-1}\bmod n$, there exists integer $k$ such that $(a^{-1}\bmod n)\,a=1+k\,n$. It holds
$$\begin{align}(a^{-1}\bmod n)(a(bG))&=((a^{-1}\bmod n)a)(bG)\\
&=(1+k\,n)(bG)\\
&=1(bG)+(k\,n)(bG)\\
&=bG+k((n\,b)G)\\
&=bG+k((b\,n)G)\\
&=bG+(k\,b)(nG)\\
&=bG+(k\,b)\mathcal O\\
&=bG+\mathcal O\\
&=bG\\
\end{align}$$

Notice $a^{-1}\bmod n$ is unrelated to $a^{-1}\bmod p$ where $p=2^{255}-19$ is the order of the field used for coordinates of points on curve25519.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed proof, when im testing with the impl i have, when I do $a a^{-1}$, I always be getting `0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` for any $a$. So is $2^{248}$ is the point of infinity for the curve25519?

Comment: If $a\,a^{-1}$ turns out $2^{248}$ for any $a$, it's not computed right. Again, you want to compute $a^{-1}$ modulo $n$. In python 3.8 and later, that's `pow(a,-1,2**252+27742317777372353535851937790883648493)`. Then you do point multiplication of this integer with $a(bG)$ and get $bG$.